# Scheduled Task on CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, scheduled-tasks, cakephp-3.0

I work on **CakePHP 3.2** Project..

I have a `Property`  Entity..

when a user creates a **property**, the admin must validate it to become **active**..
After that I put  in field called `date_of_expiration` the current date + 10 days for example ...

What I want is that this **property** expires in this date (current date + 10 day).. By changing a field called `status` from **active** to **inactive**..

I searched in Google and i found that what i nead called **Sheduled Task**..

I ask about the best way to do this in CakePHP 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Create Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) with the function to find an expired property and change the value to inactive.
2. [Run Shell from CronJob](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) every day at 00:00:00

Comment: is Cron job the best way there is no other solutions because i have to found more than one solution ?

Comment: Is the simplest way. Cron run in the background, at the scheduled time invoke the shell script, which perform what you need.

Comment: This can be used on windows ?

Comment: Yes, you can follow this instructions http://b2evolution.net/man/set-up-windows-scheduled-task OR if you want test your Shell simple open console / terminal run ```cake yourshellname```

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which would call a function in your controller. Your function then would select all the records from your `properties` table, check if `date_of_expiration` is expired and then set the `status` to `inactive`.

You have to allow the method to be called without you are logged in and possibly disable the CSRF component (if you are using it):

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->Auth->allow('cronjob_expiration_date');

    if(in_array($this->request->action, ['cronjob_expiration_date'])) {
        $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
    }
}
```

This is necessary, because the cron job "user" is not logged in.

Comment: Wrong way, cron need to call cakephp shell instead controller method

Comment: @Salines In my project I set up something similar with a cron job calling my method from the controller. It's basically just calling a specified URL. It works without any problem and very reliable. Thank you for the downvote... But I like the idea of the shell as well.

Comment: The problem with today people like to abstract everything, even the CLI if they can and as much of it as they can.  They call it *replacing the sysop*

Comment: @st2erw2od Why not simply when can be complicated? OK, your approach requires that applications use routing, beforefilter and more walking around, instead of fewer lines of code.

Comment: @st2erw2od can you explain more i didn't understund very well your approach

Comment: @ST2OD mischievous users may just start calling the "specified URL" at random intervals which may reduce data integrity and even break the app if poorly written. I can imagine using a unusual `action` name but the point is why all the hassle, is it worth?