# CakePHP3 Crontab to run controller method

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

```
public function checkDueDate() {
        require_once(ROOT .DS. "vendor" . DS . "message360" . DS . "message360.php");
        $message360 = new \Message360API\Lib\Message360;
        $message360::getInstance();
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }
```

So I have this method in a Controller named Subscriptions Controller, I've omitted the rest of the code which does a process because its not relevant for the question. I've learned how to set up a crontab and what its used for. I want to implement a crontab in order to run this controller method once a day.

I've tried following some outdated posts on google but none of them seem to be working. 
Does anyone know how I would go about implementing this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36769204/1127933

Comment: Successfully made the shell and when I run it from the console it works as it should. i set up a crontab but its not working..

Comment: 30 12 * * * bin/cake message360 <- which is the name of my shell but its not running anything.

Comment: Is this question superseded by http://stackoverflow.com/q/37892488/761202 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use cpanel or whatever you are using to manage your webserver and add

```
curl your-url.com/yourcontroller/checkDueDate
```

then setup the duration in the provided ui

Comment: Care to be a little bit more specific? I haven't deployed my application yet, so you're saying to set it up after I set it up?

Comment: i would suggest you set it up after you've deployed

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to encourage the use of curl for "controller" crons, but this does answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to run it as a shell command instead of a controller method. It works now! Thank you all for your input.