# CronJob not running CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

In my CakePHP3 application, I have a shell called Message360.

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

class Message360Shell extends Shell
{

    public function initialize() 
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadModel("Subscriptions");
    }

    public function main()
    {
        require_once( ROOT .DS. "vendor" .DS. "message360" .DS. "message360.php");

        $Message360 = new \Message360Api\Lib\Message360;
        $Message360::getInstance();
        $Message360->setOptions(array(
            "account_sid" => "c77ddb33-8dbb-f6c2-2f95-59e0173b24d9",
            "auth_token" => "dd032baa394e66a9aa32b0282d9d0390",
            "response_to_array" => true
        ));

        //Get today's date, then send SubReminds based on contact method
        $now = Time::now();
    }
}
```

I've removed a lot of the actual code since its not pertinent to the question.

The Shell runs the main function fine when I manually run it via bin/cake message360

However, I installed a CronTab in order to run it at a specific time, but after testing it many times, I've yet to get it to run.

I did a crontab -e in the terminal 
Got the working directory of my CakePHP application via navigating to my applications root and copy/pasting the output of the "pwd" command.

My crontab -e looks like this

ex) this is what i had for a test run

32 06 * * * cd /home/danielparkk/Desktop/SubReminder && bin/cake message360

Is there something wrong with how I'm doing this?

Comment: Do you really have a space in `cake message360`? If so, then you need to quote the whole path.

Comment: You mean I need the working directory of the message360 shell itself?

Comment: Is message360 a parameter you're passing to cake?

Comment: it's the name of the shell and I'm running a method called main.

Comment: I just followed what was on the documentation for the site but it doesn't seem to be working http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Comment: read error logs on server and your cakephp application. Setup email notificaton when runing cron, then you can see where and what is wrong in your setup

Comment: if `cd /home/danielparkk/Desktop/SubReminder && bin/cake message360` works for you (the answer to which is not clear from the question) and doesn't via cron - the problem is likely permissions.

Comment: the shell works when i do bin/cake message360 however the problem is i have a crontab that isn't running my shell. is the path to root /home/danielparkk/Desktop/SubReminder/webroot or /home/danielparkk/Desktop/SubReminder/src or /home/danielparkk/Desktop/SubReminder/

Comment: Does anyone have any exampeles of cronjobs..